# notepad++ regex: Removing multiple lines between keywords

Tags: regex, notepad++

Present situation:

```
ODR+1'&
DPT+::LAS'&
ARR+::RSW'&
DAT+:021214'&
TVL+20141202:0835:20141202:1830:0+LAS+RSW+WN+596+ET'&
APD+73W+:1+:'&
APD+::415'&
CAR+O:WN'&
DAT+AA:021214:1400::::MKE*AD:021214:1430:::73W'&
ODR+2'&
DPT+::RSW'&
ARR+::LAS'&
DAT+:111214'&
TVL+20141211:1030:20141211:1500:0+RSW+LAS+WN+274+ET'&
APD+73W+:+:1'&
APD+::450'&
CAR+O:WN'&
DAT+AA:111214:1225::::MDW*AD:111214:1300:::73W'&
UNT+29+1'
```

I want to remove everything between the second **DAT** to **UNT** i.e I want this as final:

```
ODR+1'&
DPT+::LAS'&
ARR+::RSW'&
DAT+:021214'&
TVL+20141202:0835:20141202:1830:0+LAS+RSW+WN+596+ET'&
APD+73W+:1+:'&
APD+::415'&
CAR+O:WN'&
DAT+AA:021214:1400::::MKE*AD:021214:1430:::73W'&
ODR+2'&
DPT+::RSW'&
ARR+::LAS'&
DAT+:111214'&
UNT+29+1'
```

As there are multiple TVL segments present that can't be distinguished and I want to keep the first one and just delete the second one.... I am having more difficulties

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
^(.*?DAT.*?)DAT.*?(UNT)
```

Try this.Repalce by `$1$2`.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/lZ5mN8/56

Answer (score 0):

You need to use DOTALL mode `(?s)` to make dot to match even line brakes,

```
(?s)^(.*?DAT.*?DAT[^\n]*\n).*?\n(?=UNT)
```

Then replace the match with `$1`

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/lZ5mN8/55)

Seems like you're trying to remove the lines after third DAT. If yes, then you could try the below,

```
(?s)^(.*?DAT.*?DAT.*?DAT[^\n]*\n).*?\n(?=UNT)
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/lZ5mN8/60)

Comment: @hwnd why you deleted your answer?

Comment: Sorry my bad... I gave the wrong input and output...your answer works though for the initial query

Comment: is that you want to remove all the lines from second DAT or third DAT?